# Maven repository caching: Why is there a cache miss in the second run despite being cached in the first run?

Tags: java, maven, caching, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm encountering an issue with Maven repository caching in my CI/CD pipeline where there seems to be a cache miss in the second run despite the cache being successfully resolved in the first run. So the pipeline downloads maven dependencies again. What am I missing?

Here are the details:

Logs from first run:

```
2024-02-16T06:07:55.0601063Z ##[section]Starting: Cache Maven local repo
2024-02-16T06:07:55.0604747Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-16T06:07:55.0604864Z Task         : Cache
2024-02-16T06:07:55.0604921Z Description  : Cache files between runs
2024-02-16T06:07:55.0604995Z Version      : 2.198.0
2024-02-16T06:07:55.0605064Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-02-16T06:07:55.0605132Z Help         : https://aka.ms/pipeline-caching-docs
2024-02-16T06:07:55.0605208Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-16T06:07:55.4414221Z Resolving key:
2024-02-16T06:07:55.4553411Z  - "funcs" [string]
2024-02-16T06:07:55.4571469Z  - maven   [string]
2024-02-16T06:07:55.4571795Z  - "Linux" [string]
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5018041Z  - pom.xml [file] --> 5893AE16A5F30361F4225A94E477DB4CD1996348660AD3CFBB1F4DBF72753257
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5064081Z Resolved to: "funcs"|maven|"Linux"|EpdW7VOO9P62oHHqI9TxsjUKX3NemXThFSh/NjDbSf8=
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5126152Z Resolving restore key:
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5126751Z  - maven   [string]
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5127024Z  - "Linux" [string]
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5133145Z Resolved to: maven|"Linux"|**
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5133337Z Resolving restore key:
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5133577Z  - maven [string]
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5133821Z Resolved to: maven|**
2024-02-16T06:07:55.5592310Z Using default max parallelism.
2024-02-16T06:07:56.4382488Z Using default max parallelism.
2024-02-16T06:07:56.4391109Z Max dedup parallelism: 192
2024-02-16T06:07:56.4391465Z DomainId: 0
2024-02-16T06:07:56.5918440Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 2c5e36a2-f0aa-46fc-8d04-fce0bc3c204d
2024-02-16T06:07:56.5943617Z Hashtype: Dedup64K
2024-02-16T06:07:56.7734517Z Getting a pipeline cache artifact with one of the following fingerprints:
2024-02-16T06:07:56.7735134Z Fingerprint: `"funcs"|maven|"Linux"|EpdW7VOO9P62oHHqI9TxsjUKX3NemXThFSh/NjDbSf8=`
2024-02-16T06:07:56.7735886Z Fingerprint: `maven|"Linux"|**`
2024-02-16T06:07:56.7736226Z Fingerprint: `maven|**`
2024-02-16T06:07:57.3874838Z There is a cache miss.
2024-02-16T06:07:58.0799644Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 1 events with X-TFS-Session 2c5e36a2-f0aa-46fc-8d04-fce0bc3c204d
2024-02-16T06:07:58.0924753Z ##[section]Finishing: Cache Maven local repo
```

Logs from second run:

```
2024-02-16T06:21:28.1316213Z ##[section]Starting: Cache Maven local repo
2024-02-16T06:21:28.1319938Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-16T06:21:28.1320071Z Task         : Cache
2024-02-16T06:21:28.1320128Z Description  : Cache files between runs
2024-02-16T06:21:28.1320203Z Version      : 2.198.0
2024-02-16T06:21:28.1320263Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2024-02-16T06:21:28.1320345Z Help         : https://aka.ms/pipeline-caching-docs
2024-02-16T06:21:28.1320422Z ==============================================================================
2024-02-16T06:21:28.4851948Z Resolving key:
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5007633Z  - "funcs" [string]
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5025467Z  - maven   [string]
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5026109Z  - "Linux" [string]
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5434800Z  - pom.xml [file] --> 5893AE16A5F30361F4225A94E477DB4CD1996348660AD3CFBB1F4DBF72753257
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5478850Z Resolved to: "funcs"|maven|"Linux"|EpdW7VOO9P62oHHqI9TxsjUKX3NemXThFSh/NjDbSf8=
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5537145Z Resolving restore key:
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5537814Z  - maven   [string]
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5538343Z  - "Linux" [string]
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5543267Z Resolved to: maven|"Linux"|**
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5543652Z Resolving restore key:
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5544353Z  - maven [string]
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5544566Z Resolved to: maven|**
2024-02-16T06:21:28.5983821Z Using default max parallelism.
2024-02-16T06:21:29.4158957Z Using default max parallelism.
2024-02-16T06:21:29.4167148Z Max dedup parallelism: 192
2024-02-16T06:21:29.4169349Z DomainId: 0
2024-02-16T06:21:29.5509867Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session e570c636-2828-41f0-a57d-df6db6a4a793
2024-02-16T06:21:29.5531316Z Hashtype: Dedup64K
2024-02-16T06:21:29.8068742Z Getting a pipeline cache artifact with one of the following fingerprints:
2024-02-16T06:21:29.8069565Z Fingerprint: `"funcs"|maven|"Linux"|EpdW7VOO9P62oHHqI9TxsjUKX3NemXThFSh/NjDbSf8=`
2024-02-16T06:21:29.8070600Z Fingerprint: `maven|"Linux"|**`
2024-02-16T06:21:29.8070948Z Fingerprint: `maven|**`
2024-02-16T06:21:30.8048244Z There is a cache miss.
2024-02-16T06:21:31.6162213Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 1 events with X-TFS-Session e570c636-2828-41f0-a57d-df6db6a4a793
2024-02-16T06:21:31.6285835Z ##[section]Finishing: Cache Maven local repo
```

My Pipeline

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - "master"

variables:
  MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER: $(MAVEN_HOME).m2/repository
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)"

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: "CI"
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: "Build/Test Service"
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        container:
          image: maven:3.9-eclipse-temurin-21
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 0

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: "Cache Maven local repo"
            inputs:
              key: '"funcs" | maven | "$(Agent.OS)" | pom.xml'
              restoreKeys: |
                maven | "$(Agent.OS)"
                maven
              path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)

          - task: Maven@3
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: "pom.xml"
              goals: "clean install"
              options: "-DskipTests $(MAVEN_OPTS)"
            displayName: "Maven Install"
```

changed to `$(MAVEN_HOME).m2/repository` since I'm using maven:3.9-eclipse-temurin-21 container image

Answer (score 0):

Testing on my side, there isn't the same issue when using your YAML file. The only change I made was that I removed "pom.xml" from the key (To resolve error on my side). I can see `There is a cache hit: "funcs"|maven|"Linux"` in the log after my first successful run.
[image]

According to this doc [Cache task: how it works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#cache-task-how-it-works), after all steps in the job have run and assuming a **successful** job status, a special "Post-job: Cache" step is automatically added and triggered for each "restore cache" step that wasn't skipped. This step is responsible for saving the cache. Please ensure that "Maven Install" succeed on your first run.